# Row autofit property not working properly

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have one excel sheet

Width of Column A is 70 and the word wrap property is ON.

And the content in the cell is of 287 words/1950 characters. Now when i try the row autofit function, its not working properly. Some of the content is still not visible. How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Only the first 1024 characters will be shown in the grid, this IS how it works. You can see the complete content in the formula bar without a problem, just not in the sheet grid.

As this is the normal functionality it isn't an issue.

However If you want to see more you should either split the content in parts of =<1024 characters OR put the content in a textbox.